# If once record exists filter out associated records

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following table (doesn't include all data):

```
Company   Account   Acct_Unit   System
10        10510     10000000    GL
10        10510     10000000    ML
10        10990     10000020    ML
10        25310     10000000    AP
10        25310     10000000    BR
```

I am trying to remove all account string records (Company/Account/Acct_Unit) where one record = ML.

Here is what my table should look like after the removal:

```
Company   Account   Acct_Unit   System
10        25310     10000000    AP
10        25310     10000000    BR
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Hint: Use `not exists`.

Comment: What about the GL? why do you expect it to be removed?

Comment: If it's query filtering and not actual record deletion, use a where clause with a condition. in your case: select * from table where system <> 'ML'.
 If you intended to delete the records from the table for good, use delete from table where system = 'ML'

Comment: @Y.S I want to remove all associated records, since the second record (10,10510,10000000,ML) will be removed then the first record (10,10510,10000000,GL) should also be removed since these two records have the same value for company, account, and acct_unit

Comment: in that case, you need something like: select * from table where account not in (select account from table where system = 'ML')

Comment: @Y.S thanks! that worked!

Comment: Great, happy it helped. cheers

Answer (score 0):

No exists works.  Alternate is a left join following the logic of : take the table and left join it to a subselect on itself where system = 'GL'.  If a ml record is found, the left joined table account field will be populated, so look for records where the left joined record is null.

```
select a.* from following_table a
left join (select account,Acct_Unit from following_table where System = 'GL') b
on a.account = b.account and a.acct_unit = b.acct_unit
where b.account is null
```

For some reason I left company out of the join.  Feel free to add it back in if you need.